# Why can't I see print statements in the debug area when I run my code in simulator?

Tags: debugging, printing, console

When I run my code, the print statements aren't showing up.

[simulator run, no print statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu58g.png)

To rule out code/logic problems, I tried a fresh new program to test; still no output.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print("view did load")
    }
}
```

[after running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsC03.png)

Any ideas?

Thanking you!

- Xcode 11.5
- macOS 10.15.5

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

Click to expand and see the Console.

(Near the bottom in the Debug Area,
in the bottom right corner near the trash icon.)

[Expand Console pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vPFL.jpg)